# Ajax post to local URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, json

I'm really clueless on how to accomplish this. I've searched the internet, but probably in the wrong areas with the long keywords.

I want to run a RESTful api.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https//my.url/",
    data: { ...some json... }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "CREATE EVENT Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
```

I know that I can not do a cross domain call from ajax, so I want to an ajax post to a local URL and then do server code HTTP POST to the remote server.

What does it look like to do an ajax post to a local url? What does the local URL page look like?

I'm programming in Django and Javscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Vaishak's answer. You map the view in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^postdata$', 'name_of_your_app.views.postdata')
```

Then you call it with jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/postdata/",
   // ...
```

Comment: I'm confused on what you mean by 'application.views.postdatatoserver'. What does this do and what should me views.py look like? Currently: def postdata(request):
    return render(request, 'livestream/postdata.html')

Comment: Thanks. makes sense now. Json is currently blank, but I'm going to start working on that now

Comment: Don't forget to pass the json content type in the return of the view. And if you're using a form. Don't forget to set the CSRF token in your ajax call and template

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the browser console, you may find an exception stating that the request is prevented because of [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) violations

If the domain from which your page is loaded is different from the domain to which the the request is made then it will not work because of [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) restrictions.

If the server supports [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) then you can work around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do cross-domain calls if you're posting data. You cannot `load` or get data from another page because of  [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy).

If you decide to do it the way you've described, i.e by posting to a local URL and then letting the server make the next request, then you don't need to do anything special.
Your local URL is another page/method in your application.

map the method that needs to handle this request in your `urls.py` and forward the request to that.

Example:

If the `urls.py` entry is like below

```
url(r'^postdata$', 'application.views.postdatatoserver')
```

Then your URL on the test server would be

```
http://localhost:8000/postdata
```